# Firebase Crash Reporting is not transmitting crash report when using Real iOS device

Tags: ios, firebase, firebase-crash-reporting

I have integrated Firebase Crash Reporting in my xcode Project by watching their tutorials  [here](https://firebase.google.com/docs/crash/)

Crash Reports are uploaded successfully when using simulator . but it shows error below when i am using a real device and crash reports are not uploaded. I searched for solution but have not got any which can solve this problem .

```
`<Error> [Firebase/Crash][I-CRA100001] Failed to transmit crash: Error Domain=com.google.FirebaseCrash Code=1 "Upload failed" UserInfo={NSLocalizedDescription=Upload failed, NSLocalizedFailureReason=HTTP Error Code 400: <NSHTTPURLResponse: 0x174039920> { URL: https://mobilecrashreporting.googleapis.com/v1/crashes:batchCreate?key=AIzaSyB8TUDtvxRxo5Kx3nEtIRKYlXDG%5Fj%2DRXmY&alt=json } { status code: 400, headers {
        "Cache-Control" = private;
        "Content-Encoding" = gzip;
        "Content-Length" = 157;
        "Content-Type" = "application/json; charset=UTF-8";
        Date = "Thu, 01 Jun 2017 08:49:40 GMT";
        Server = ESF;
        Vary = "Origin, X-Origin, Referer";
        "alt-svc" = "quic=\":443\"; ma=2592000; v=\"38,37,36,35\"";
        "x-content-type-options" = nosniff;
        "x-frame-options" = SAMEORIGIN;
        "x-xss-protection" = "1; mode=block";
    } }}`
```

at last i changed my version from 1.0 to 2.0 but it  is still not working .

Comment: Have you found a solution for this? If so can you share it ?

Comment: what i remember i did something in key chain sharing and i  used the release  key.  but the crash report will not go when you are  running the app in Xcode using device or simulator. run the app without Xcode in a device or simulator and if your app crash you will get the report.